# Is there a more common word than "mnemonicization"

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the word for the process of *creating* a mnemonic?

I coined (? did I?) the verb "to mnemonicize" and the noun "mnemonicization"

Google shows *so few*  results for these, 25 results for "mnemonicization" and 0 for "mnemonicisation".

I am now hunting for established words that may be more common.

Comment: @user66974 I want the process of creating a mnemonic, not the process of memorising

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first usage of **mnemonicize** and **mnemonicization** I can track down appears in an academic article, Ross, R.J. (1998). [The memorial culture of Early Modern English lawyers: Memory as keyword, shelter, and identity, 1560-1640](https://digitalcommons.law.yale.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1187&context=yjlh). *Yale Journal of Law & the Humanities 10*(2):

> The golden chain's guarantee of divinely ordained  harmony in the arts, for example, becomes an anchor of memory, its original purposes overlaid, *mnemonicized*, so to speak. [...] Law's "reason," its foundation and justification, underwent a similar metamorphosis or *mnemonicization*.

It has some features of other academic terminology - Greco-Latin origin, verbing a noun, making a highly technical point (*mnemonicize* as making a mnemonic) rather than going for something more mistakeable (like *memorize*, which need not involve a mnemonic at all).

A slightly simpler and more established word would be **mnemonize**, which dates back to the 1830s. It isn't common - it's marked *rare* by the OED - but I really don't know of anything more common that fits exactly what you need ([mnemonize, v.](https://oed.com/view/Entry/120431)):

> *rare.*   *transitive*. To remember or express by means of a mnemonic formula.
>
> [...]
>
> 1988   Re: Replacing the Desktop Metaphor in comp.windows.misc (Usenet newsgroup) 24 Dec.   The desktop metaphor attempted to solve one perceived problem with the then current generation of computers, namely replacing the often cryptic commands of command line driven operating environments with icons which were mentally easy to *mnemonize*.

Comment: I will use mnemonization, thank you very much for showing the results of your exploration

Comment: @theonlygusti I don't think 'mnemonize' is what you're looking for. OED states it means 'remember'. You're looking for a word for 'make a mnemonic out of'.